# Как подключить Laravel-Filemanager к CKeditor5?

Tags: laravel

Как подключить загрузку файлов через laravel-filemanager к CKEdifot5

```
ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
            image: {
                uploadUrl: {
                    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '/laravel-filemanager?type=Images',
                    filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/laravel-filemanager/upload?type=Images&_token=',
                    filebrowserBrowseUrl: '/laravel-filemanager?type=Files',
                    filebrowserUploadUrl: '/laravel-filemanager/upload?type=Files&_token='
                }
            },
            heading: {
                options: [
                    { model: 'paragraph', title: 'Параграф', class: 'ck-heading_paragraph' },
                    { model: 'heading1', view: 'h1', title: 'Заголовок 1', class: 'ck-heading_heading1' },
                    { model: 'heading2', view: 'h2', title: 'Заголовок 2', class: 'ck-heading_heading2' },
                    { model: 'heading3', view: 'h3', title: 'Заголовок 3', class: 'ck-heading_heading3' },
                    { model: 'heading4', view: 'h4', title: 'Заголовок 4', class: 'ck-heading_heading4' },
                    { model: 'heading5', view: 'h5', title: 'Заголовок 5', class: 'ck-heading_heading5' },
                    { model: 'heading6', view: 'h6', title: 'Заголовок 6', class: 'ck-heading_heading6' },
                ]
            }
        })
        .catch( error => {
            console.log( error );
        });
```